# SSLSocketFactory verifyHostname unable to resolve subdomain

Tags: java, networking, ssl-certificate

i am using the WebDav library *sardine* from https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine. Sardine uses [SSLSocketFactory](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) an the error thrown says:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'test.example' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=example, ...)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465)
```

I am not fluent in Java Network Programming, hints in the right direction would be great.

But I am able to connect to *test.example* via my File Manager.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate CommonName (CN) should be test.exmple but it is CN=example. This is why the hostname can't be verified.

Comment: I recognized that, too. But the JRE cacert file should resemble the standard Linux cacert file. So I find it quite confusing that my file manager Nautilus seems to find the certificate while the JRE does not.

Comment: It is possible to disable the hostname verification. Maybe your other tool has done exactly that.